# Parse Month Day ('%B %d') date column into datetime using current year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in the following format

```
Date
June 22
June 23
June 24
June 25
```

I am trying to convert this column to datetime within a pandas df with the format YYYY-mm-dd

How can I accomplish this? I was able to format the date and convert to mm-dd but not sure how to add the current's year since it's not present in my Date column

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%B %d')
```

Results:

```
Date
1900-07-22 
1900-07-21         
1900-07-20 
1900-07-19
```

Desired results:

```
Date
2021-07-22 
2021-07-21         
2021-07-20 
2021-07-19
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].add(' 2021'), format="%B %d %Y")

0   2021-06-22
1   2021-06-23
2   2021-06-24
3   2021-06-25
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Suggested by @HenryEcker, to add the current year instead of specifying `2021`:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].add(f' {pd.Timestamp.now().year}'), format="%B %d %Y")
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].add(f' {pd.Timestamp.now().year}'), format="%B %d %Y")` current year option.

Comment: @HenryEcker. In 2022, this solution will not work if the OP really wants 2021 :-) :-) :-) I'm kidding. Your solution is elegant.